# Only One Product Variant added to Cart, and It's always the first one added to my db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, product, cart, product-variations, online-store

I'm setting up a simple online store with no user system - just a session following a cart.
Currently, I am able to select a Product (could be thought of as a product category), and within that product page select a ProductVariant (product_variant_id) belonging to it.

The problem is that when I add different product_variants, only the first one that is saved to the db is ever added to the cart. I can select the product_variants in the dropdown, but again only the first one added to the db in my record is added to the cart as an order_item.

My relevant Models:

```
Product

  has_many :product_variants, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :order_items, :through => :product_variants

ProductVariant

  belongs_to :product
  has_many :order_items, dependent: :destroy

OrderItem

  belongs_to :order, optional: true
  belongs_to :cart, optional: true
  belongs_to :product_variant
  belongs_to :product

Cart 

has_many :order_items
```

And here is my product show page in show.html.erb with the option to select a product_variant

```
<%= link_to products_path do %>
<h4>Back to store gallery</h4>
<% end %>

<section class="flexbox">
  <div class="flex">
      <%= image_tag @product.image_1.show.url %>
  </div>
  <div class="flex">
      <h2><%= @product.title %></h2>

      <div class="product-description">
        <h5>Description:</h5>
          <p><%= @product.description %></p>
      </div>
  </div>
</section>


<%= simple_form_for [@product, @product_variant, @order_item] do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :quantity %>

  <%= f.button :submit, "Add to cart" %>
<% end %>



Product selection: <br>
<select name="product[product_variant_id]">
    <% @product.product_variants.each do |product_variant| %>
        <option value="<%= product_variant.id %>"><%= product_variant.item %>/<%= product_variant.size %>/<%= product_variant.color %>/<%= number_to_currency product_variant.price_in_dollars %></option>
    <% end %>
</select>
```

Lastly, here is my order_items controller

```
class OrderItemsController < ApplicationController
  
  def create
    @product = Product.friendly.find(params[:product_id])
    # find the product_variant
    @product_variant = ProductVariant.find(params[:product_variant_id])
    # quantity? - comes from the form data
    @quantity = form_params[:quantity]
    @current_cart.order_items.create(product: @product, product_variant: @product_variant, quantity: @quantity)
    flash[:success] = "Thanks for adding to your cart"
    redirect_to product_path(@product)
  end
  
  def update
    @product = Product.friendly.find(params[:product_id])
    @product_variant = ProductVariant.find(params[:product_variant_id])
    @order_item = OrderItem.find(params[:id])
    @order_item.update(form_params)
    flash[:success] = "Thanks for updating your cart"
    redirect_to cart_path
  end
  
  def destroy
    @product = Product.friendly.find(params[:product_id])
    @product_variant = ProductVariant.find(params[:product_variant_id])
    @order_item = OrderItem.find(params[:id])
    @order_item.delete
    flash[:success] = "Product removed from cart"
    redirect_to cart_path
  end
  
  def form_params
    params.require(:order_item).permit(:quantity)
  end
end
```

Thanks for any insight into what might be going wrong here, and please don't hesitate if you need me to provide any more relevant code, would be happy to.

Aaron

Comment: There are a lot of issues with this code. First off you don't want to place both the product_variant amd product foreign keys on the products table. Just use product_variant  and set up an indirect assocation.

Comment: Second - you're not handling invalid user input at all. Don't just use `.create` and assume that it will always succeed unless you want to get angry calls at 3:am. Use `.save` and check if it was actually successful and re-render the form if it was not.

Comment: Third - The triple nested route implied by `simple_form_for [@product, @product_variant, @order_item]` has got to go. https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#limits-to-nesting

Comment: do you mean don't place product foreign key on order_items table?

Comment: when i change .create to .save i get an

'undefined method `save' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>'

The product variant id is adding to the cart and I can remove it, I see the cart updating -- but again it's as if I can only select one product_variant_id and it to cart, even when other's appear to be selected in the dropdown.

Comment: No I mean rewrite the code so that you create the instance with '.new' and assign it to a variable and then call '.save' on it.

Comment: Max, thanks for the recommendation! In my order_items controller i wrote under 'def create':

```
@order_item = @current_cart.order_items.new(form_params)

@order_item.save
```

And I can finally add the other product_variants to my cart